# Bootstrap modal is not showing. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show modal when it clicking "reportpet" but it not displaying modal. How can I resolve this error please help me.

URL:

```
http://newseinstein.com/Rwork/index.php/Pet/view/104
```

HTML:

```
   <span class="text">
       <a href="#" class="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="locationreport" id="reportpet">Report</a>
   </span>
```

Modal Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="locationreport" role="dialog" style="display: none;"> 
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS code:

```
  $("#reportpet").click(function(){
    $("#locationreport").show();
  })
```

Comment: When using the bootstrap modal there is no need for additioanl Jquery/JS. Did you inlcuded the bootstrap js-file in your document?

Comment: @empiric Yes I am loading bootstrap.js

Comment: you are might be looking for this https://jsfiddle.net/girish28892/DTcHh/32322/

Answer (score 3):

Change your data-target to `data-target="#locationreport"` you need to add `#` before the `id` of the modal

```
<span class="text">
       <a href="#" class="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#locationreport" id="reportpet">Report</a>
</span>
```

[**See bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/zA2JoFv3oq)